# What is the best content fallback practice used for JS-based web apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spine.js

I am building my first Spine.js application.  In the case of a non-javascript-capable browser, are most not bothering with the fallback?  I'm sure it's case-by-case.  What is the best implementation?  Should I be displaying the static content on the page and hiding it with JS when available?  Another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted case is usually to display a minimal amount of content, mostly for search engines.

I've seem "most" smaller apps not care about fallback and just tell browsers that JS is required.